# ViewPager tab's disappeared

Tags: android, view

I have a ViewPager from the support package in android with 5 tabs.
Sometimes (I can't really tell when it going to happen, there is no legality behind it) the buttons of the tabs disappeared.
I can't reproduce it and debug it because it happen randomly.

Is it happen to someone? any help real by really appreciated

Thanks =))